# python tkinter multiple canvases and game lag. is this memory-leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple movement program in tkinter it runs well for a while bur then starts to lag and the circle starts to skip around the screen. I have a lot of canvases on screen could that be the problem?

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
flag = BooleanVar()
flag.set(False)
move = BooleanVar()
move.set(False)
carecter_posision_x = IntVar()
carecter_posision_y = IntVar()
carecter_posision_x.set(325)
carecter_posision_y.set(400)
direction = StringVar()
def update():
    global canvas
    canvas = Canvas(app,width=650,height=500,bg='Blue')
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,400,655,505,fill='Green',outline='Green')
    canvas.create_oval(carecter_posision_x.get(),carecter_posision_y.get(),carecter_posision_x.get()-30,carecter_posision_y.get()-30,fill='Red')
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
def jump(event):
    def up():
        carecter_posision_y.set(carecter_posision_y.get()-2)
        update()
    def down():
        carecter_posision_y.set(carecter_posision_y.get()+2)
        update()
    if flag.get() == 0:
        for i in range(0,200,4):
            app.after(i,up)
        for i in range(200,400,4):
            app.after(i,down)
        flag.set(True)
        def set_flag():
            flag.set(False)
        app.after(400,set_flag)
    else:
        def right():
            carecter_posision_x.set(carecter_posision_x.get()+2)
        def left():
            carecter_posision_x.set(carecter_posision_x.get()-2)
        if direction.get() == 'Right' and carecter_posision_x.get() < 650:
            for i in range(0,200,4):
                app.after(i,up)
                app.after(i,right)
            for i in range(200,400,4):
                app.after(i,down)
                app.after(i,right)
            flag.set(True)
            def set_flag():
                flag.set(False)
            app.after(400,set_flag)
        if direction.get() == 'Left' and carecter_posision_x.get() > 30:
            for i in range(0,200,4):
                app.after(i,up)
                app.after(i,left)
            for i in range(200,400,4):
                app.after(i,down)
                app.after(i,left)
            flag.set(True)
            def set_flag():
                flag.set(False)
            app.after(400,set_flag)
def key_press(event):
    direction.set(event.keysym)
    if flag.get() == 0:
        move.set(True)
        def game_loop():
            if event.keysym == 'Right' and carecter_posision_x.get() < 650:
                carecter_posision_x.set(carecter_posision_x.get()+2)
            if event.keysym == 'Left' and carecter_posision_x.get() > 30:
                carecter_posision_x.set(carecter_posision_x.get()-2)
            update()
            if move.get() == 1:
                canvas.after(1,game_loop)
        game_loop()
    flag.set(True)
def key_release(event):
    if event.keysym != 'Up':
        flag.set(False)
    move.set(False)
app.bind_all('<KeyPress>',key_press)
app.bind_all('<KeyRelease>',key_release)
app.bind_all('<Up>',jump)
update()
def stop_layers():
    app.delete("all")
    app.after(20000,stop_layers)
app.after(20000,stop_layers)
app.mainloop()
```

i have tired resetting the canvases by using:

```
def stop_layers():
        app.delete("all")
        app.after(20000,stop_layers)
    app.after(20000,stop_layers) 
app.after(20000,stop_layers)
```

it is supposed to clear the the build up of canvases every 20 seconds but I still get the same problem

is this a memory leak?

how can i fix this?

Comment: You could monitor memory usage with Task Manager etc. to verify that it is in fact a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your script but I think you need this information:

`id1 = canvas.create_rectangle(...)` and `id2 = canvas.create_oval(...)`. These methods return ids that you can put into `canvas.item_config(id2, bg='red')` and `canvas.coords(id1, x1, y1, x2, y2)` to change the created forms. Unlike other UIs you do not need to repaint anything. You can reshape and configure the existing elements.